# T-SQL query to sort a column alphabetically except the ending number

Tags: sql-server

How can I write a T-SQL query to sort a column alphabetically taking in account the ending number as a numeric value?

In other words, I would not take in account digits that could be in the middle of the string so to simplify the problem.

By example:

```
a1XBNR1
a1XBNR10  <-- this should go after a1BRN2
a1XBNR2
```

Here a sample code that does not sort properly:

```
-- Alphanumeric sorting with T-SQL

USE [AdventureWorks2012]
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable
(
       id varchar(50) NULL
)

DELETE dbo.TestTable
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('a1XANR1')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('a1XANR10')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('a1XANR2')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('a1XANR20')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('a1XANR3')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('a1XB11')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('a1XB2')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('b1XBNR20')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('b1XB30')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('b1XB2')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('AB100')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('1')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('AB1')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('A1')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('B2')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('A11')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('B20')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('B21')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('AB10')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('B3')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('AB100')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('2')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('B1')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('B32')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('11')
INSERT INTO dbo.TestTable (TestTable.id) VALUES ('A10')


-- Attempt 1 - Syntax not supported by T-SQL
SELECT *
FROM   db.TestTable
ORDER  BY left(id, 1)  -- 1st letter as text
     , substring(fest, '\d+')::int NULLS FIRST  -- first number in string as int
     , id  -- whole columns as cheap tiebreaker

-- Attempt 2 - cannot have digit in the middle of the string
-- Error: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '1XBNR1' to data type int.
SELECT id
FROM dbo.TestTable
ORDER BY LEFT(id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',id)-1), -- alphabetical sort
         CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(id,PATINDEX('%[0-9]%',id),LEN(id))) -- numerical
```

Comment: reverse the string... get the numbers up to the pat index of the first character.  reverse the string back now you have the 2nd sort column.  Then sort by your original string less the second values at the end then the 2nd string.  something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9221851/how-to-remove-any-trailing-numbers-from-a-string 2nd answer.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I will look in that direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `patindex()` and `reverse()` order by the left part before the trailing set of numbers, and the converting the last set of numbers to an integer for the rest of the sort.

```
select *
from testtable t
order by 
    left(id,len(id)-patindex('%[^0-9]%',reverse(id))+1)
  , convert(int,right(id,patindex('%[^0-9]%',reverse(id)+' ')-1))
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/XHY76045

returns:

```
+----------+
|    id    |
+----------+
| 1        |
| 11       |
| 2        |
| A1       |
| A10      |
| A11      |
| a1XANR1  |
| a1XANR2  |
| a1XANR3  |
| a1XANR10 |
| a1XANR20 |
| a1XB2    |
| a1XB11   |
| AB1      |
| AB10     |
| AB100    |
| AB100    |
| B1       |
| B2       |
| B3       |
| B20      |
| B21      |
| B32      |
| b1XB2    |
| b1XB30   |
| b1XBNR20 |
+----------+
```

Comment: That's exactly what I needed.  Thanks so much!